# JQUERY - Restore class on mouse out

Tags: jquery

You can check this website I am creating:

http://www.tinybigstudio.com/proyectos/golfycia/

If you hover over "PRECIO" it changes the ball image, but when on mouse out, I want the image of the full ball to be restored and I can´t do it.

This is the Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#secciones span").hover(function () {
        $("#golfball img").removeClass("opaque");

        var imageToShow = $(this).attr("id").replace("for-", "");
        $("#golfball #" + imageToShow).addClass("opaque");

    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#secciones span").mouseout(function () {
        $("#image-1").addClass("opaque");

    });
});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#secciones span").hover(function () {
            $("#golfball img").removeClass("opaque");

            var imageToShow = $(this).attr("id").replace("for-", "");
            $("#golfball #" + imageToShow).addClass("opaque");

        }, function () {
            $("#golfball #image-1").addClass("opaque");
            $("#golfball #image-2").removeClass("opaque");
        });
    });
```

important - remove this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#secciones span").mouseout(function() {
        $("#image-1").removeClass("opaque");

    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine everything:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#secciones span").hover(function () {
        $("#golfball img").removeClass("opaque");

        var imageToShow = $(this).attr("id").replace("for-", "");
        $("#golfball #" + imageToShow).addClass("opaque");

    },function () {
        $("#image-1").removeClass("opaque");
    });
});
```

Comment: @user792558 thats because i think you are remving the class from the wrong object...

Answer (score 0):

The `hover` method can take a second argument, which is a function to call on mouseout.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to use the `toggleClass()` method:

```
$("#secciones span").hover( function () { $(this).toggleClass("opaque"); });
```

It's short and simple. Just set your default background image for the golf ball. And make a new class that overrides the background. Use the above code to toggle the new class on and off as you hover over the golf ball.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that what is hovered shoud be the < span >´s

Answer (score 0):

your `mouseout` is removing `opaque` class from `#image-1` instead of `#image-2`

try this

```
$("#secciones span").hover(function() { // mouse over
    $('#image-2').addClass('opaque');
}, function() { // mouse out
    $('#image-2').removeClass('opaque');
});
```

Comment: The code had a slight mistake, it should be<script>
`code`$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#secciones span").hover(function () {
        $("#golfball img").removeClass("opaque");

        var imageToShow = $(this).attr("id").replace("for-", "");
        $("#golfball #" + imageToShow).addClass("opaque");

    },function () {
        $("#image-1").addClass("opaque");
    });
});
</script>`code`